# LZSS vs. LZ77 compression difference

Tags: c, compression, difference, lz77

Can someone please explain the difference between the `LZSS` and the `LZ77` algorithm. I've been looking online for a couple of hours but I couldn't find the difference. I found the LZ77 algorithm and I understood its implementation.

But, how does `LZSS` differ from `LZ77`? Let's say if we have an string `"abracadabra"` how is `LZSS` gonna compress it differently from `LZ77`? Is there a C pseudo-code that I could follow?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, both terms LZ77 and LZSS tend to be used very loosely, so they do not really imply very specific algorithms. When people say that they compressed their data using an LZ77 algorithm, they usually mean that they implemented a dictionary based compression scheme, where a fixed-size window into the recently decompressed data serves as the dictionary and some words/phrases during the compression are replaced by references to previously seen words/phrases within the window.

Let us consider the input data in the form of the word

```
abracadabra
```

and assume that window can be as large as the input data. Then we can represent "abracadabra" as

```
abracad(-7,4)
```

Here we assume that letters are copied as is, and that the meaning of two numbers in brackets is "go 7 positions back from where we are now and copy 4 symbols from there", which reproduces "abra".

This is the basic idea of any LZ77 compressor. Now, the devil is in the detail. Note that the original word "abracadabra" contains 11 letters, so assuming ASCII representation the word, it is 11 bytes long. Our new representation contains 13 symbols, so if we assume the same ASCII representation, we just expanded the original message, instead of compressing it. One can prove that this can sometimes happen to any compressor, no matter how good it actually is.

So, the compression efficiency depends on the format in which you store the information about uncompressed letters and back references. The original paper where the LZ77 algorithm was first described ([Ziv, J. & Lempel, A. (1977) A universal algorithm for sequential data compression. IEEE Transactions on information theory, 23(3), 337-343](https://doi.org/10.1109/TIT.1977.1055714)) uses the format that can be loosely described here as

```
(0,0,a)(0,0,b)(0,0,r)(0,1,c)(0,1,d)(0,3,a)
```

So, the compressed data is the sequence of groups of three items: the absolute (not relative!) position in the buffer to copy from, the length of the dictionary match (0 means no match was found) and the letter that follows the match. Since most letters did not match anything in the dictionary, you can see that this is not a particularly efficient format for anything but very compressible data.

This inefficiency may well be the reason why the original form of LZ77 has not been used in any practical compressors.

SS in the "LZSS" refers to a paper that was trying to generalize the ideas of dictionary compression with the sliding window ([Storer, J. A. & Szymanski, T. G. (1982). Data compression via textual substitution. Journal of the ACM, 29(4), 928-951](https://doi.org/10.1145/322344.322346)). The paper itself looks at several variations of dictionary compression schemes with windows, so once again, you will not find an explicit "algorithm" in it. However, the term LZSS is used by most people to describe the dictionary compression scheme with flag bits, e.g. describing "abracadabra" as
|0a|0b|0r|0a|0c|0a|0d|1-7,4|
where I added vertical lines purely for clarity. In this case numbers 0 and 1 are actually prefix bits, not bytes. Prefix bit 0 says "copy the next byte into the output as is". Prefix bit 1 says "next follows the information for copying a match". Nothing else is really specific, term LZSS is used to say something specific about the use of these prefix signal bits. Hopefully you can see how this can be done compactly, in fact much more efficiently than the format described in LZ77 paper.